# Loss of data from sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using sqlite to store data in my application. The data gets stored correctly (I can see it in the database) and is fetched correctly.

However, about a day later, when I go back into my app, the database has lost some of the data. I have put debug in to verify that what is being displayed is what is stored in the DB. 
Does anyone know of any examples or scenarios where this happens? And why it happens and what I can do to stop it from happening?

Thanks

Comment: First see where your application is install. in memory card or in phone?

Comment: I'm testing it out on a Galaxy Nexus - Therefore no memory card. It is stored on the phone

Comment: Are you starting a transaction, and then forgetting to finish it? Post some examples of your code where you save data which is later lost.

Comment: Graham, that appears to be the reason, or at least, that is a problem in my code. I am just running some tests to confirm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sound as if you may be starting a transaction, and not finishing it. The correct way to manage transactions is this:

```java
db.beginTransaction();
try {
    // insert data here
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```